# How to enable a specific log-tag in an AOSP framework library

Tags: logging, android-source

In AOSP I am trying to debug a vendor specific gralloc implementation. I see the implementation has ALOGx statements that print useful information, but I don't see these in logcat.

The code uses the `LOG_TAG` `"gralloc"`. I have tried to pass `ro.log.tag.gralloc=DEBUG` to Android during boot, but to no avail. I have also used `adb shell setprop persist.log.tag.gralloc DEBUG` to create a persistent property, but that also did not enable the log messages in logcat.

I have searched the AOSP documentation and StackOverflow for details how to manage log levels, but have not found how to enable a specific log level. Any help is appreciated.